# XMPP Libraries for Metro Apps in WinRT

Tags: c#, xmpp, windows-runtime, ejabberd, agsxmpp

Could you please list down some XMPP Libraries which supports for Metro Apps in WinRT?

Thanks!

Comment: XMPP is a protocol and has nothing to do with Metro Apps. Any XMPP library for windows should be usable.

Comment: no, WinRT is a special subset of the .NET Framework with many new features and changes. Only libraries which target the WinRT Framework will work, you can't use "any" library.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267456/is-there-any-free-xmpp-library-which-supports-winrt/18342553#18342553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MatriX is available for WinRT (https://www.ag-software.net/matrix-xmpp-sdk/)