# Is there any free XMPP library which Supports WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, xmpp

Could anyone say me the XMPP library that supports WinRT, I've tried Jabber-Net, agsXMPP, those are not working. . .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559363/xmpp-libraries-for-metro-apps-in-winrt

Comment: WinRT has a new socket implementation and the old (eg Silverlight) does not exist. This is why you have to find a library which is developed for WinRT or you have to port an existing library... You will not be able to simply recompile a Silverlight library in a WinRT project...

Comment: @Rico Suter Can we able to create that Sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no free XMPP library to be used in WinRT. Only avaialable library is Matrix dll.

Comment: Which is currently at 1399 euro per developper.

Answer (score 4):

I've not tried it, however there is an open-source xmpp library distributed under the lgpl v3, used in a Windows 8 chat app.

Here is the library: https://github.com/PaulFreund/xmpp, and here is the app (I think you can use it as a reference): https://github.com/PaulFreund/Chat/