# Facebook chat API/XMPP X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, xmpp, facebook-c#-sdk

Please read my question first before voting it off-topic considering **questions asking us to recommend or find a tool/library.**

I am creating a WinRT app for only Facebook chat. I checked the developer site, I am recommended to use [Facebook Chat via the Jabber/XMPP service](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/). I tried to find that feature in [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.net) but it's not available in it.

I searched for XMPP library and found [this](http://www.ianquigley.com/A91_Facebook_Chat_Authentication_in_C.html). It's ASP.NET project though, I decided to port it for WinRT, but I read the [latest comment](http://www.ianquigley.com/A91_Facebook_Chat_Authentication_in_C.html#comment-1030737814) in that blog post. It's telling this is also no longer working.

So anyone there know how to use chat API using WinRT supported XMPP library ? If library is not availble then can any one guide for any tutorial, I can't find relevant tutorial.

**Those who think, chat/messenger is not available programmatically, please see [IM+](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/im-instant-messenger/99c049c4-5ef8-4b17-802e-4cf5463d4ef3/m/ROW) app in Windows Store.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, finally I found WinRT supported XMPP library as well as full fledged chat app. Kudos to developers.

[Is there any free XMPP library which Supports WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18342553/1230188)

Answer (score 0):

From the Facebook .NET SDK FAQ - http://facebooksdk.net/docs/faq/

> **Does Facebook SDK for .NET support Facebook Chat?**
>
> Facebook SDK for .NET doesn't support the Facebook chat (nor do we
>   have any plans to support it in the future). Facebook chat is based on
>   the xmpp protocol thus any [existing XMPP
>   .NET](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) libraries would work
>   with Facebook Chat.